# PDO getting undefined variable

Tags: php, insert, blob

i am new to php and i am trying "Php code to upload images in database table with blob data type "... 
I'm getting this error as above mentioned in Heading

```
<?php include 'connection.php';

 function insertBlob($filePath, $mime) 
  {
    $blob = fopen($filePath, 'rb');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO files(mime,data) VALUES(:mime,:data)";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':mime', $mime);
    $stmt->bindParam(':data', $blob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

    return $stmt->execute();
 }

 $strSQL-> insertBlob('C:\Users\Vishal\Desktop\house.png',"image/png");

 if(mysqli_query($con, $strSQL)){
 echo "Records added successfully.";
 } else{
 echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $strSQL. " . mysqli_error($con);
 }

 ?>
```

[image]

Comment: What is on line 19 of `blob.php`

Comment: from where you have got this? ` $strSQL-> `

Comment: Are you mean `$strSQL = insertBlob(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

The error says that the variable `$strSQL` is undefined.

`$this->pdo->prepare` doesn't make sense in your function as well.

You're mixing OOP with Functional concepts.

**Updated**

I assume `connection.php` is class, and `$strSQL` is instance of that class, **`insertBlob()` should be inside the class definition not out**.

So under include, create new instance,

`$strSQL = new WhatEverClass()`

```
class MyConnection {
     protected $pdo;

     public function __construct() {
        $this->pdo = ...
     }

     public function insertBlob($filePath, $mime) 
      {
        $blob = fopen($filePath, 'rb');

        $sql = "INSERT INTO files(mime,data) VALUES(:mime,:data)";
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':mime', $mime);
        $stmt->bindParam(':data', $blob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

        return $stmt->execute();
     }

}

    $strSQL = new MyConnection();
    $strSQL->insertBlob('C:\Users\Vishal\Desktop\house.png',"image/png");
```